# Form data sent with AJAX request not updating sql table

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, ajax

Im having an issue getting a sql table to update with the form data sent from a Jquery AJAX POST.

I've tried mysql_error() and it returns no errors.

I added an additional line to my textarea "-Test Test"

this is being recognised on the Form data
[image]

At the bottom you see test text, this is part of the text being entered into notetext1 which is then made notetext2 in this **submitNoteText.php**:

```
<?php include 'connectionDetails.php'; ?>

<?php


if (isset($_POST['noteid1'], $_POST['notetext1'])) 
{

    $noteid2 = $_POST['noteid1'];
    $notetext2 = $_POST['notetext1'];

    $query = "UPDATE Notes SET Note = " . $notetext2 . " WHERE NoteID = ".$noteid2;
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query) or die(mysql_error());
}

sqlsrv_close($conn);

?>
```

However i refresh my table in my database and the text has not been added despite the successful post?
[image]

The JQuery:

```
function submitNoteText()
{
    var noteid = <?php if(isset($_POST['noteid'])){ echo $_POST['noteid'];} ?>;
    var notetext = $("#ta1").val();

    var dataString = 'noteid1=' + noteid + '&notetext1=' + notetext;

    console.log("NoteID: " + noteid);

    if(noteid == ''||notetext == '')
    {
        alert("NoteID or Text is blank");
    }
    else
    {   
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "submitNoteText.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
                alert("Successfully saved!");
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
};
```

Comment: I hope this is not all brand new work - your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Use prepared statements to protect your data. Also - you're using sqlsrv_query but then mysql_error!!! These are two entirely separate libraries for different DB engines. Which DB are you using? P.S. Also, the mysql_* libraries have been deprecated for some time, and removed entirely in PHP7 due to vulnerabilities. If your DB is MySQL, use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: Hi thanks, for the comment, i will adjust to protect from injection once its working, its only a handfull of people i work with that will use it, its not accessible to anyone else. Like i said i'll still protect it though, the mysql_error was a mistake i forgot to take out. i use a MS SQL if that means anything.

Comment: you still can't trust those handful of people, or trust that they will not input something by mistake that will be a problem. Even doing something as simple as putting an apostrophe ( ' ) into the note text could potentially crash it. Anyway, Does sqlsrv_errors give you any clues? http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-errors.php

Comment: Might also be worth checking that the content of `$query` looks as you expect just before the SQL is executed - you could echo it to the response and show it in your page, for debugging purposes. If so, then try to execute the generated statement directly in SQL Server (using SSMS or whatever) and see if it works.

Comment: I added a var_dump on if(isset) on the $_POST['notetext1'] and it returned the else instead so its not actually populating $_POST['notetext1'] with the form data. hmmmm

Comment: Please, for the love of security use `PDO` to connect to sqlsrv. Secondly a value should be quoted: `SELECT mytable FROM col WHERE val = 'QUOTED VALUE'`

Comment: check in your browser's network tab when the ajax request is made, to see what the request body actually looks like. Does it actually send the value with the correct field name?

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the data as an object instead of a string.
So change this line:

```
var dataString = 'noteid1=' + noteid + '&notetext1=' + notetext;
```

to

```
var data = {noteid1: noteid, notetext1: notetext};
```

And then you should change the request to use this data so it becomes:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "submitNoteText.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
            alert("Successfully saved!");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Still the same issue, its sending through the data no problem, in debug it stores notetext1 with all the text i need, however  `if (isset($_POST['noteid1'], $_POST['notetext1'])) 
{

 $noteid2 = $_POST['noteid1'];
 $notetext2 = $_POST['notetext1'];

 $stmt = "UPDATE Notes SET Note = '?' WHERE NoteID = ?";
 $params = array($notetext2, $noteid2);

 $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $stmt, $params);

 if ($stmt === false) 
 {
  die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
 }
}
else
{
 echo "No Data";

}` is not inserting into data base for some reason.